# What is the difference between "become sensitized" and "become sensitive" in the enclosed text?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

I wonder what the difference between "become sensitized" and "become sensitive" in this context?

> With time to appraise the ostracism episode, individuals **become** differentially **sensitized** based on (i) the specific needs that are thwarted, (ii) their own individual differences, and (iii) their assessment of who ostracizes and why.

Why is not just "become differentially sensitive"?

Here is the whole paragraph if it helps to understand it better:

> To be ostracized is to be ignored and excluded. How does ostracism affect individuals? Considerable research has now shown that the initial (reflexive) reactions to even the most minimal forms of ostracism are painful and distressing. Fundamental needs of belonging, self-esteem, control, and meaningful existence are thwarted; sadness and anger increase. These effects emerge despite individual differences or situational factors that should lead logically to easy dismissal. With time to appraise the ostracism episode, individuals become differentially sensitized based on (i) the specific needs that are thwarted, (ii) their own individual differences, and (iii) their assessment of who ostracizes and why. These differences lead to need-restorative behaviors that range from being overly socially attentive and susceptible to influence to being aggressive and antisocial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sensitize has a technical meaning "cause (someone or something) to respond to certain stimuli" (lexico).  Whereas "sensitive" has a range of meanings including "responsive to slight changes", "having a delicate understanding of other peoples feelings" or "easily distressed by slight changes". (adapted from lexico)

Using the more technical term is appropriate and precise in a scientific document, such as this one.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a further question? In this case, which stimuli the individuals are caused to respond to? Or what the individuals become sensitized to?

Comment: [Which stimuli cause individuals to respond? What do individuals become sensitized to?]

Comment: I don't know, I'm not an expert on psychology.  I can describe the meaning of the words, but I don't really understand the science in the article.